# Negative values in SVMRank

Tags: svm, rank

I'm using SVM-Rank.

Train file:

5 qid:1 1:67.3 2:923.1 3:0

2 qid:1 1:0 2:789.54 3:56.9

5 qid:1 1:0 2:56.7 3:0

...

And test file:

1 1:0 2:923.1 3:45.67

1 1:23.3 2:67.29 3:42.7

1 1:237.43 2:81.6 3:0

...

When execute the ".exe" I get unexpected values in output. For example:

-22.01801808

-2.00162188

0.71802803

-7.918182978

8.95675672

Why I get negative values?

Answer (score 0):

In your case it's obviously larger numbers, but the principle stays the same.

Examples of limits in java are:

```
int: −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. 
long: -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

So be careful, if your qid Integer has a limit, then the value will become negative

Comment: My qid Integer is not large is like: qid:1 or qid:2

Answer (score 0):

The values in the predictions file do not have a meaning in an absolute sense - they are only used for ordering.

https://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_rank.html